# Write to file most common words by counter with linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, unix, terminal

I want to write to a file the words that appear at least X times in the text.
For example, for:

```
a
b
a
c
b
```

and X = 2 I would get:

```
a
b
```

Comment: What is your research so far? What have you tried by yourself?

Comment: I found a way to return the most frequent words with:
sort test.txt | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -n 12 
or: 
sort test.txt | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -n 12 | sed -E 's/^ *[0-9]+ //g'

Comment: The accepted answer to this question [text-file word occurrence count](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39039/get-text-file-word-occurrence-count-of-all-words-print-output-sorted/39044#39044) may meet your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the basics, though it will be quite slow in a large word list:-

```
set Count
sort < WordList | uniq | while read w; \
    do [ $(grep -c "^$w$" WordList) -ge $1 ] && echo $w; done
```

A faster answer (thanks to Kamil Maciorowski):-

```
set Count
sort < WordList | uniq -c | while read c w; do [ $c -ge $1 ] && echo $w; done
```

This assumes:-

- You will set your own `FileList` and `Count` entries.
- The words are one-per-line in `WordList`.
- Case is significant (eg `The` and `the` are different).
- This is the command-line entry: in a script, `set Count` would be omitted and passed as a parameter.

This should get you started, though you will almost certainly need to modify for your precise needs.

Comment: what do you mean when you say: You will set your own FileList and Count entries.?

Comment: It may be faster with `uniq -c` (the further logic needs to be rebuilt, of course).

Comment: @ShaniGamrian - `FileList` is the name of the file containing the words; `Count` is the number of entries you want to check for. I thought that would be obvious: sorry if it wasn't clear to you.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - Thanks for your suggestion: I'd forgotten about `uniq -c` and it's a lot simpler and faster. I've added it to my answer.

Comment: Thank you!!!
How do I write the results to a file?

Comment: @ShaniGamrian - Redirect the output by adding `>OutputFile` at the very end of the statement (after `done`). You may want for clarity to bracket the whole statement: `{ sort ... done } > OutputFile`.

Comment: How do you do the same thing but without removing the duplicate rows? I tried to remove the uniq -c part but it didn't work

Comment: @ShaniGamrian - Short answer: you can't, because this is fundamental to the solution. Why would you want to? You are removing them from work streams, not the original file, which is completely unaltered.

Comment: I want to read the rows from the file into Python and count the number of times they appeared. Is there a way to write the number of times they appeared next to the line?

Comment: @ShaniGamrian - If you modify the script slightly to add the count to the output file `sort < WordList | uniq -c | while read c w; do [ $c -ge $1 ] && echo $w $c; done >WordCounts`, then you can search through the original list and match the entries `while read w; do grep "^$w " WordCounts || echo $w; done <WordList`. This will show the bare words when the counts are under the threshold, but you can change it to suit. Please note: (1) you are now asking things well outside your original question, which has been answered; and (2) this site is not a script-writing service.